# jQuery autocomplete not working connected to mySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete form that was working completely fine.  I leave my laptop and come back and now it doesn't work anymore.

My database is named wallettest

My table is named population and has 4 columns:
Id, location, slug, Population.

I have 3 files: index.php, script.js and ajax_refresh.php.

Doing some testing, it seems it's not accessing my ajax_refresh.php which connects me to my database.  So from there, I decided to put my ajax_refresh.php in my index.php file.  Well, now I'm connected to my database but getting errors (I don't get why it wouldn't connect me in the first place, I had the right syntax in my file:

```
js file:"$.ajax({
            url: "ajax_refresh.php",
```

Anyways, file now looks like this and the error I get is below:

index.php:

```
<?php
// PDO connect *********
//CHECK TO SEE IF CONNECTION IS MADE
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","butthead"); 
 if ($db) {
 echo("- Connection to database successful -");
 }
 else if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }


function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wallettest', 'root', 'butthead', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
} 


$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM population WHERE slug LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $slug = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['slug']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['slug']).'\')">'.$slug.'</li>';
}

// END AJAX_REFRESH.PHP
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Autocomplete using PHP/MySQL and jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">

        </div><!-- header -->
        <h1 class="main_title">Autocomplete using PHP/MySQL and jQuery</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <form>
                <p>Table consists of : ID, Location, Slug, Population </p>
                <br><br>
                <div class="label_div">Search for a Slug : </div>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input type="text" id="slug" onkeyup="autocomplet2()">
                    <ul id="list_id"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <p>List will be ordered from Highest population to lowest population (Top to bottom)</p>
                <br><br>
        </div><!-- content -->    
        <div class="footer">
            Powered by Jason's Fingers</a>
        </div><!-- footer -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
// autocomplete : this function will be executed every time we change the text
function autocomplet2() {
    var min_length = 3; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#slug').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#list_id').show();
                $('#list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#list_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // Changes input to the full name on selecting
    $('#slug').val(item);
    // Hides list after selection from list
    $('#list_id').hide();
}

function change()
```

Error:[image]

Comment: The answer is obvious, check to see why keyword isn't being sent to the PHP script.

Comment: forms default to GET if not explicitly giving it a POST method and I don't see POST in your JS and no name attribute bearing `keyword`. Plus, why the `mysql_` functions inside the same code as PDO? a bit confusing. Plus where's this `autocomplet2()` function? *Too many unknowns here Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: oh yeah, the code you want us to look in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31820341/ got it. Well, someone gave you answer; take it up with them. You're reposting.

Comment: That post is an entirely different question, this is a separate question from that

Comment: Realized I was missing the .js file, I put it in here

Comment: subject makes no sense when it clearly shows in image that you are connecting to database

Comment: It makes some sense if you read the post

Answer (score 0):

There are many things funny in your code:

1. Missing form method (default is GET).
2. Mixing the `mysql_*` and PDO API's. You can remove the entire conditional where you use `mysql_connect()` as you never ever use the connection (`$db`) created there.
3. Missing name attribute from your input element:

   `<input type="text" id="slug" name="keyword" onkeyup="autocomplet2()">`

What is generating the error is this line in your PHP:

```
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
```

When you initially load the page the variable `$keyword` is not defined because the `$_POST` array has not been set. The way that you prevent that is by checking to see if the array has been set before assigning a value to the variable:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
    // other code relying on $keyword being set should go here
}
```

Take note of the comment in the code above. *Any* code relying on the keyword being set, such as your database query, should be inside of the conditional. There is no sense in running that code if the variable is not set.

Finally, your code organization is going to start to become hard to manage when you decide to expand what you have here. Consider separating the PHP, HTML and JS from each other to allow for easier management.